# What animated film featured a girl and a knight on a planet with strange gravity?

Tags: identify-this-movie, animation

I recall watching an animated film around 2010-2012 featuring a girl and a knight.

- The DVD I watched was French, but I do not know if that was the original language.
- The knight had a queue hairstyle.
- There was a rabbit-like creature who followed the girl and knight.
- The main characters traveled on a planet that had unusual gravity. The planet seemed to be floating apart into pieces and the situation became worse as the film went on.
- There was a king or wizard who had a giant mechanical clock predicting the end of the world.
- The knight fought a giant monster using some knitting needles.

Comment: Do you know the year of the release? How was the animation? Like anime or new? Do you remember any notable dialogue or a song from a movie?

Comment: It was possibly released around 2010. The animation might have been computer generated.

Comment: Patema inverted (2013)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patema_Inverted The main characters are a girl and a guy (no rabbit). Scientist almost destroyed the Earth: now part of the people an of the planet *fall* upward.

Comment: @mattiav27 Any reservations to fleshing that out into an actual answer?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I do not remember the mechanical clock part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The movie you are thinking of is [Dragon Hunters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Hunters) (or in French: Chasseurs de dragons)

The character who fights with "Knitting Needles" is Lian-Chu

> Lian-Chu is a sword-wielding, muscle-bound warrior who actually deals out the dragon slaying. In contrast to Gwizdo, he is more kindhearted and honorable. He is also an avid knitter.

The rabbit-like creature is actually a non-evil dragon who follows the two main characters around.

> Hector is their pet dragon who does not possess the evil nature or the great size of the ones they hunt and acts like a dog.

The girl you are thinking of is actually a boy.

> Gwizdo is the brains of the group and negotiates their contracts with the helpless people terrorized by dragons.

Yes my research came from Wikipedia BUT I checked their sources and they were okay.

Comment: Are those parts that are in quotes actually taken from some external resource? If yes, please add where they are from, preferably with a link. If not, why are they in quotes?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Okay, I fixed that.